# Don't know why I receive `error: forward declaration of <class>`

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
class AP_InertialSensor_Backend;

class AP_InertialSensor
{
public:
    const Vector3f  &get_gyro(uint8_t i) const { return drivers[primary_instance]->_gyro[i]; }
private:
    AP_InertialSensor_Backend *drivers[INS_MAX_INSTANCES];

    void detect_instance(uint8_t instance);    

    /// primary IMU instance
    uint8_t primary_instance=0;
};

#include <AP_InertialSensor_Backend.h>
```

Anyway, I am receiving these errors:

```
In member function 'const Vector3f& AP_InertialSensor::get_gyro(uint8_t) const':
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class AP_InertialSensor_Backend'
error: forward declaration of 'class AP_InertialSensor_Backend'
```

I have other same projects and it worked then, but I do not know what is failing.

I would apreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have the include at the end and also why forward declare if you are just going to include the header anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're accessing a member `_gyro` of `AP_InertialSensor_Backend` before the class is defined.

To fix it, move the implementation of `get_gyro` to the cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you have not included the header file for `AP_InertialSensor_Backend` before you use it. You did include a forward reference, but the only thing that allows you to do is declare a pointer to that class.